# Trying to understand why make is failing

Tags: makefile, fortran

I can't use this Makefile to compile "balance_test" ...

```
FLAGS=-g

OBJS=balance.o balance_drv.o
SRCS=$(OBJS:.o=.F90)

balance_test: $(OBJS)
        gfortran $(FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

balance.mod : balance.o
balance.o : balance.F90
balance_drv.o: balance_drv.F90 balance.mod

clean:
        rm balance_test *.o *.mod


.SUFFIXES : .F90 .o

.F90.o :
        gfortran -c $(FLAGS) $^
```

... because `make` thinks that balance.o depends on balance.mod, and so it thinks there is a circular dependency.  (`balance_drv.o` *does* depend on `balance.mod` because `balance_drv.F90` uses `module balance`, by the way.)

I fixed this by specifying the compile statement specifically for balance.o and balance_drv.o.  But I would like to know what exactly I am misunderstanding about suffix rules, because I don't want it to bite me when I have a much bigger Makefile to write.

Comment: What is the message you get on your make invocation (and how do you invoke)?

Comment: What is the purpose of `.F90.o :
        gfortran -c $(FLAGS) $^`? It does not seems to be a rule that fills the expected purpose of compiling F90 files to object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a suffix rule of the form

```
%.o : %.mod
    ...
```

Your rule:

```
.SUFFIXES : .F90 .o
```

*adds* (or reiterates) two suffixes, but it does not disable the other suffix rules. To do that, add one more rule:

```
.SUFFIXES :
.SUFFIXES : .F90 .o
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've read discussions on this, but this is the first time I've seen this simple but important point spelled out.  Thanks!